# What is meant by "Would you be happy to put a no obligation visual together for me?"

Tags: obligation

I get reply from one of my client today

```
Would you be happy to put a no obligation visual together for me?
```

What does he mean to say? As there is no more lines, we could not get what he meant to say.

Comment: Did you ask your client for clarification? I'm not sure what this has to do with English.

Comment: Which bit don't you understand? ie is 'Visual' a noun that is commonly used in your business? Is it the 'no obligation' that confuses you, or perhaps the question as to whether it would make you happy?

Comment: `no obligation visual`

Comment: He means you're doing him a favor, but he doesn't expect to return it.

Comment: ...possibly including paying for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably means that the client would like you to produce the 'visual' (presumably part of the work that you offer), but he does not wish, at this stage, to enter into any formal agreement. That is, I think he wants to make it clear that he is not offering anything (in terms of future work and/or compensation) at this stage of the negotiation process.